# failed to run rspec on ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

do you know how to fix this? I was trying to run rspec on Ruby but it shows like this..

```
LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- rspec/expectations
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
No examples found.


Finished in 0.01334 seconds (files took 1.46 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples

Finished in 0.01334 seconds (files took 1.46 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Comment: Does this happen on some specific file? What does running just an empty `rspec` show?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar issue (cucumber),I had two different versions of **rspec-expectations** gem installed, and the newer one was causing a conflict. I checked my Gemlist, discovered I had the required version and a newer one, so I simply uninstalled the newer version and I was able to run my cucumber tests. Moreover, there are many more solutions referenced [here](https://groups.google.com/g/cukes/c/CyitMVkzotY/m/Y8LDWRJyWX4J) .